# Emacs 24 GUI on OXS turn off transparency

Tags: osx, emacs24.4

I'm using GNU Emacs 24.5.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0, NS apple-appkit-1265.21) of 2015-04-10 on builder10-9.porkrind.org (from emacsformacosx.com) and I've got this annoying transparency going on and I don't know how to disable it. See attached image (it's not easy to spot but it's there).

[image: Took a photo with my phone since it's not screen-grab-able]

Comment: Can you describe what the problem is because it is hard to spot whatever is the spot you are referring to? Start with location of the spot.

Comment: Do you mean the transparency of the title bar? That is a OSX Mavericks feature, it is not emacs specific.

Comment: I've added another photo (took it with my phone) since I realised the issue is not noticeable in the screenshot. I'm pretty sure now it's got nothing to do with Emacs since I can see the issue on other apps too but maybe someone knows about it.

Comment: It's possible the `alpha` frame parameter is set to something other than 100 (full opacity).  Try evaluating `(set-frame-parameter (selected-frame) 'alpha 100)` and let us know if you're still seeing the transparency issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're working on a MBPro Retina or Thunderbolt Display, or any display that uses in-plane switching (IPS) technology, your issue is likely image persistence.

I was experiencing the same problem on my Mac with all programs. I would close or hide a window (or Emacs frame), and I could see a very faint remnant of that window (frame). It also occurred when I switched OS X 'spaces.'

After putting it off for some time your question prompted me to finally investigate the issue. I would recommend Apple's article on [Avoiding image persistence on Apple displays](https://support.apple.com/en-nz/HT202580). The punchline:

> To clear the persistent image, allow the screen saver to run for approximately as long as the image was being displayed.